# How to separately start and stop multiprocessing processes in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I use a dedicated Python (3.8) library to control a motor drive via a USB port.

The Python library provided by the motor control drive manufacturers (ODrive) allows a single Python process to control one or more drives.

However, I would like to run 3 processes, each controlling 1 drive.

After researching options (I first considered virtual machines, Docker containers, and multi-threading) I began believing that the easiest way to do so would be to use `multiprocessing`.

My problem is that I would then need a way to manage (i.e., start, monitor, and stop independently) multiple processes. The practical reason behind it is that motors are connected to different setups. Each setup must be able to be stopped and restarted separate if malfunctioning, for instance, but other running setups should not be affected by this action.

After reading around the internet and Stack Overflow, I now understand how to create a `Pool` of processing, how to associate processes with processor cores, how to start a pool of processes, and queuing/joining them (the latter not being needed for me).

What I don't know is how to manage them independently.
How can I separately start/stop different processes without affecting the execution of the others?
Are there libraries to manage them (perhaps even with a GUI)?

Comment: Each process can be given its own message queue where you can send messages to stop, etc. if you don't use a pool.

Comment: @MattClarke, can they also be separately started? I'm not sure how to practically envision how I'd tell a setup "Start doing function, using these parameters" after other processes have already been started from the Python script.

Comment: If you don't use a pool and instead create the processes manually then you have finer grained control over when they start, etc. TBH it isn't much more complex than using a pool.

Comment: @MattClarke, thanks for the tip. In practice then I'd rather use a sort of "console approach" rather than sticking to a "script approach". So, I'd have to manually run (and manage) processes each time by means of independent commands. Do I see this correctly, in your view? 
Assuming this approach, would there be an easy way/command to monitor what's currently running? E.g., Process X running on core 2; Process Y on core 3; Core 4 is free?

Comment: I think what you suggest is achievable. I would give each process two queues: one for control and one for it to report back status information. The 'report' queues can then be queried to get the respective statuses (e.g. motor position). The processes themselves have a `is_alive` method to see if they are up or not.

Comment: @MattClarke, if you feel like structuring your suggestions in an answer with a skeleton of code, I'll be happy to accept it. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably do something like this:

```
import random
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue


class MotorProcess:
    def __init__(self, name, com_related_params):
        self.name = name
        # Made up some parameters relating to communication
        self._params = com_related_params
        self._command_queue = Queue()
        self._status_queue = Queue()
        self._process = None

    def start(self):
        if self._process and self._process.is_alive():
            return
        self._process = Process(target=self.run_processing,
                                args=(self._command_queue, self._status_queue,
                                      self._params))
        self._process.start()

    @staticmethod
    def run_processing(command_queue, status_queue, params):
        while True:
            # Check for commands
            if not command_queue.empty():
                msg = command_queue.get(block=True, timeout=0.05)
                if msg == "stop motor":
                    status_queue.put("Stopping motor")
                elif msg == "exit":
                    return
                elif msg.startswith("move"):
                    status_queue.put("moving motor to blah")
                    # TODO: msg parsing and move motor
                else:
                    status_queue.put("unknown command")

            # Update status
            # TODO: query motor status
            status_queue.put(f"Motor is {random.randint(0, 100)}")
            time.sleep(0.5)

    def is_alive(self):
        if self._process and self._process.is_alive():
            return True
        return False

    def get_status(self):
        if not self.is_alive():
            return ["not running"]
        # Empty the queue
        recent = []
        while not self._status_queue.empty():
            recent.append(self._status_queue.get(False))
        return recent

    def stop_process(self):
        if not self.is_alive():
            return
        self._command_queue.put("exit")
        # Empty the stats queue otherwise it could potentially stop
        # the process from closing.
        while not self._status_queue.empty():
            self._status_queue.get()

        self._process.join()

    def send_command(self, command):
        self._command_queue.put(command)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    processes = [MotorProcess("1", None), MotorProcess("2", None)]

    while True:
        cmd = input()
        if cmd == "start 1":
            processes[0].start()
        elif cmd == "move 1 to 100":
            processes[0].send_command("move to 100")
        elif cmd == "exit 1":
            processes[0].stop_process()
        else:
            for n, p in enumerate(processes):
                print(f"motor {n + 1}", end="\n\t")
                print("\n\t".join(p.get_status()))
```

Not production ready (e.g. no exception handling, no proper command parsing, etc.) but shows the idea.
Shout if there are any problems :D

Answer (score 2):

You can create multiple `multriprocessing.Process` instances manually like this:

```
def my_func(a, b):
    pass

p = multiprocessing.Process(target=my_func, args=(100, 200)
p.start()
```

and manage them using multiprocessing primitives `Queue`, `Event`, `Condition` etc. Please refer to the official documentation for details: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

In the following example multiple processes are started and stopped independently. `Event` is used to determine when to stop a process. `Queue` is used for results passing from the child processes to the main process.

```
import multiprocessing
import queue
import random
import time


def worker_process(
    process_id: int,
    results_queue: multiprocessing.Queue,
    to_stop: multiprocessing.Event,
):

    print(f"Process {process_id} is started")
    while not to_stop.is_set():
        print(f"Process {process_id} is working")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        result = random.random()
        results_queue.put((process_id, result))

    print(f"Process {process_id} exited")


process_pool = []
result_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
while True:
    if random.random() < 0.3:
        # staring a new process
        process_id = random.randint(0, 10_000)
        to_stop = multiprocessing.Event()
        p = multiprocessing.Process(
            target=worker_process, args=(process_id, result_queue, to_stop)
        )
        p.start()
        process_pool.append((p, to_stop))

    if random.random() < 0.2:
        # closing a random process
        if process_pool:
            process, to_stop = process_pool.pop(
                random.randint(0, len(process_pool) - 1)
            )
            to_stop.set()
            process.join()

    try:
        p_id, result = result_queue.get_nowait()
        print(f"Completed: process_id={p_id} result={result}")
    except queue.Empty:
        pass

    time.sleep(1)
```